# Resolving multipath interference when modelling radio wave propagation

Tags: waves, velocity, interference

I am creating a raytracer to model the propagation of radio waves from a simple router.

I am assuming that the rays have a frequency of 2.4GHz and a velocity of the speed of light. The router has an initial power of 1mW.

For simplicity I use FSPL (free-space path loss) to model the degradation of the signal over distance.

When one ray intersects a point, it is easy to calculate the RSS (received signal strength) in dBm. You take the distance the ray has traveled, plug it into FSPL, and convert the result from watts to dBm.

However, it is unclear how to resolve the effects of multipath interference when 2 or more rays intersect at a given point. I am not sure, for example what the amplitude of the radio waves are, or if there any dampening effects. Can someone explain or point me to some resources on how to model this phenomenon accurately?

Comment: Do you understand how interference works? You take the vector sum of the two waves taking account of both their amplitude and phase. This quickly becomes very hard...

Comment: I'm only working in 2D, so it might be easier. Can you explain further with an example?